# How to find the last given character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

For example, there is a string `"Apple is red; Banana is yellow; Orange is orange;dummytest"`

I'd like to find the last ";" and get rid of everything after that character. Just like:

`"Apple is red; Banana is yellow; Orange is orange"`

I know some ordinary ways but what's the easiest way?

Comment: The easiest way is probably the first you found.

Comment: Just in case : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: I would imagine it would involve using the lastIndexOf and substr methods.

Comment: Use this
var myString = "linto.yahoo.com.";
var stringLength = myString.length; // this will be 16
var lastChar = myString.charAt(stringLength - 1);

Comment: @dystroy According to Murphy's law, the easiest way is usually the last one you tried.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way I can think of is to use a combination of [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [`lastIndexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) like so:

```
var s = "Apple is red; Banana is yellow; Orange is orange;dummytest";
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(";"));
//s = "Apple is red; Banana is yellow; Orange is orange"
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/tgyMN/)

---

Normally, one might be inclined to validate the input string first. Which you could do like so:

```
var isValid = s.lastIndexOf(";") > -1;
```

However, javascript wont throw an error if you use `substring` with `-1` as the length parameter (unlike C# would for example), you will just end up with an empty string result which is probably what one would want anyway.

---

Also, just for completeness, you could cut the string at the first occurrence of a character using the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function, like so:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(";"));
//s = "Apple is red"
```